# Apache2 - default SSL/HTTPS page - aka. <VirtualHost *:443>

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, https, redirect, apache2

This is a very simple question.

I have several websites hosted. Some are HTTP, some are HTTP and HTTPS. It all works.
However, if I mess up an SSL site by pointing a domain at my server where the SSL configuration is not set up yet, it will redirect to a different website instead of displaying an error. In a worst-case scenario, one domain might redirect to a competitor's website. Not good.

To better demonstrate the issue, let's say I have two company sites.

- Company A
- Company B

Let's say I have **Company A** fully set up. I migrate **Company B**'s content - but I don't have the SSL config set up yet. So I just move over the HTTP config file. When I reload Apache, it will start serving HTTP requests - but for SSL, it will "fall through" and the requests end up the first SSL configured website (sorted alphabetically).

What I want is the same as the `<VirtualHost *:80>` entry.
A default, fallback `<VirtualHost *:443>` entry.

I tried putting this in `000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine On
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But this just gives an error and breaks pretty much all hosted sites too.
How do I do this? I don't even mind just throwing an error on 443 by default because I don't even want to mess with the certificate for the host itself. But how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

- Add this to the default/top-most config file.
- Make sure you have the "snakeoil" certs installed. On Ubuntu/Debian this is the `ssl-cert` package. I already had it installed - you may already have it too.
- Remember to reload Apache2 after adding the directive. Always test your other sites too.

This will load the default Ubuntu / Debian / whatever welcome page if an SSL site is misconfigured or cannot be loaded. Still better than falling back to actual real but completely unrelated websites. (: